# Can macOS choose the "highest" wattage power source available?

Tags: macos, battery, charging, power

I have two monitors (Gigabyte M27Q) that I connect to my MacBook Pro 16" (2019, Intel) via USB-C. Both monitors are capable of power delivery, but it's super low wattage (~10-15W) and I can't disable it. I separately plug my laptop into the stock 87W power adapter and use it in clamshell mode (lid closed).

I notice that my laptop is never charging and it seems like it's trying to only draw power from the monitors rather than actual charging adapter. **Is there any way to "force" macOS to choose the highest wattage power source that's available?**

Things I've tried:

- I can work around this somewhat if I plug the USB-C power adapter in first, let it detect that's the charger, and then plug in the monitors. This is tedious because when I wake my laptop from sleep with the keyboard/mouse (via USB hub in the monitor), macOS will pick the monitor as the power source first.
- I tried switching to a USB-C to HDMI cable to "cut off" the power delivery, but something about this monitor and macOS prevents it from running at 120Hz and I lose the USB passthrough capability.

[image: Screenshot from System Information]

Comment: What is the make and model of the two monitors?

Comment: They're both Gigabyte M27Qs. Besides the low power delivery, they work great: 120Hz, built-in USB hub, and audio passthrough all over a single USB-C cable.

Comment: What is your setting in the AC power